# Дописать строку к числу

Tags: python, строки

```
i=5
while i > 0:
     код
     ElemMail.send_keys(i)
     код

i -= 1 # сдвигаем значение на 1
```

Как мне к `i` приписать строку, т. е. чтобы получалось, к примеру, `5_foo`, на следующем проходе цикла `4_foo`, `3_foo` и т. д.

Пробовал `i=str(i+'_foo')` - получил ошибку:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 3):

Преобразование типа `int` -> `str` надо выполнить до операции конкатенации строк (`str + str`)

```
i=5
while i > 0:
    код
    ElemMail.send_keys(str(i) + '_foo')
    код
    i -= 1 # сдвигаем значение на 1
```

Comment: Только что так сделал и увидел Ваш комментарий)) Спасибо за ответ!